# MySQL: How to do ordering on multi-column indexing if the first column is conditioned in a range?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table table_a, it has fields like date(varchar), user_id, and others, I create a multicolumn index index_date_user_id （date, user_id）. I want to iterate over the table with paging, like

```
 select * from table_a where date < '20210304' and date > '20210108'
     order by date, user_id limit 4 offset 0

 select * from table_a where date < '20210304' and date > '20210108'
     order by date, user_id limit 4 offset 4

 select * from table_a where date < '20210304' and date > '20210108'
     order by date, user_id limit 4 offset 8

 select * from table_a where date < '20210304' and date > '20210108'
     order by date, user_id limit 4 offset 12
```

I want there are no overlapping/duplicate rows between these paged rows. But since there is a range condition for column "date", the second column of the `index_date_user_id` does't work. If I force the index, like

```
 select * from table_a force index (index_date_user_id)
     where date < '20210304' and date > '20210108'
     order by date, user_id limit 4 offset 0
```

since the ordering in index_date_user_id is by (date, user_id), does `order by date, user_id` work? e.g, the ordering is like

```
  ('20210109', 1111), ('20210109', 1112),('20210109', 1113),
  ('20210302', 999),('20210303', 14)
```

where values like '20210108' are `date`, while 1111, 1112, 14 are user_id

**besides**, how to optimize if the `m` is very big for `limit n offset m`

Comment: `date(varchar)` how depressing. :-(

Comment: And see EXPLAINEXTENDED's excellent article on late row lookups in MySQL.

Comment: Switch to `DATE` datatype _and_ this syntax for date literals:  '2021-10-08'.  If you _still_ have an issue, test with more than a trivial 5 rows.  If you _still_ have trouble provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  _Then_ we can dig into it further.